# ebpf program loading error: unknown func bpf_l4_csum_replace#11

Tags: linux-kernel, bpf, ebpf

I am testing a nat program using ebpf. But the ebpf prog loader throws a error message:

```
221: (85) call bpf_l4_csum_replace#11
unknown func bpf_l4_csum_replace#11
```

What does it mean ? How to solve it ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A similar message could mean that your kernel does not know the BPF helper you are trying to use, because e.g. **your kernel is too old** or **the helper has been compiled out** based on the kernel configuration options. But in those cases, you would not see the name of the function in the verifier logs.

What is probably happening here is that your kernel does support the BPF helper, but **the type of the BPF program** you are trying to load **is not compatible with that helper**. For example, if your program is of type `socket_filter`, you cannot use this helper (see function [`sk_filter_func_proto()`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/net/core/filter.c?h=v5.7#n6127) used for [the check](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/kernel/bpf/verifier.c?h=v5.7#n4464)). If your program was a TC classifier instead, you would be able to use it.

Comment: Yes, you are right. XDP  program could not use this function: bpf_l4_csum_replace.